# NodeJS streams and premature end

Tags: node.js, events, stream, event-handling

Assuming a Readable Stream in NodeJS and a Data (`on('data', ...)`) event handler tied to it that is relatively slow, is it possible for the End event to fire before the last Data handler(s) has finished, and if so, will it prematurely terminate that handler? Or, will all Data events get dispatched and run?

In my case, I am working with large files and want to commit to a DB every data chunk. I am worried that I may lose the last record or two (or more) if End is fired before the last DB calls in the handler actually complete.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Event 'end' fire after last 'data' event. But it may happend before the last Data handler has finished. It is possible that before one 'data' handler has finished, next is started. It depends of what you have in your code, but it is possible that later call of event 'data' finish before earlier. It may cause errors and problems in your code.

#### Example how to cause problems (to your own tests):

```
  var fs = require('fs');
  var rr = fs.createReadStream('somebigfile.jpg');
  var i=0;
  rr.on('data', function(chunk) {
    i++;
    var s = i;
    console.log('readable:' + s);
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('timeout:'+s);
    }, 50-i*10);
  });
  rr.on('end', function() {
    console.log('end');
  });
```

It will print in your console when start each 'data' event handler. And after some miliseconds when it finish. Finish may be in different order.

## Solution:

Readable Streams have two modes 'flowing mode' and a 'paused mode'. When you add 'data' event handler, you auto set Readable Streams to flowing mode.

From [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end) :

> When in flowing mode, data is read from the underlying system and
>   provided to your program as fast as possible

In this mode events will not wait for your slow actions to finish. For your need is 'paused mode'.

From documentation:

> In paused mode, you must explicitly call stream.read() to get chunks
>   of data out. Streams start out in paused mode.

In other words: you demand chunk of data, you get it, you work with it, and when you ready you ask for new chunk of data. In this mode you controll when you want to get your data.

**How to change to 'paused mode'**:

It is default mode for this stream. But when you register 'data' event handler it switch to 'flowing mode'. Therefore not use `readstream.on('data',...)`
Instead use `readstream.on('readable', function(){...})` when it fire, then it means that stream is ready to give chunk of data. To get chunk of data use `var chunk = readstream.read();`

Example from docs:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var rr = fs.createReadStream('foo.txt');
rr.on('readable', function() {
  console.log('readable:', rr.read());
});
rr.on('end', function() {
  console.log('end');
});
```

Please read documentation for more details, because there are more posibilities when stream is auto switched to 'flowing mode'.

**Work with slow handlers and flowing mode:**

If you want/need work in 'flowing mode', there is also solution. You can pause and resume stream. When you get chunk form readstream('data'), pause stream and when you finish work then resume it.

Example from documentation:

```
var readable = getReadableStreamSomehow();
readable.on('data', function(chunk) {
  console.log('got %d bytes of data', chunk.length);
  readable.pause();
  console.log('there will be no more data for 1 second');
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('now data will start flowing again');
    readable.resume();
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: That second example doesn't seem to behave how I would have expected. If I add the "end" and/ or "finish" events, both of them are fired before the setTimeout() function completes. How can I pause for longer running tasks, during the stream, and reliably know when it has ended?

Comment: First of all, are you sure that you paused stream in "data" event?
Second thought, are you sure that you didn't resume it in other places than callback in setTimeout?
Third check, it may be possible that your stream is soo small that first "data" event drain stream and there is no more data, which means that it also triggered finishing events.

Comment: Yes, as far as I know. Here's my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57377295/aws-lambda-node-write-data-while-streaming-ends-prematurely-and-data-is-mis

I've also worked up a much smaller version of this, essentially doing what you show above. The "end" and "finished" events occur before the timeouts finish.

Comment: It is quite hard to investigate without running and debugging code. I gave you some guessing based on what I see

Comment: @TsarBomba I am seeing the same as you describe. I managed to solve by using `readableLength` prop of readableStream. In my case I checked if it was 0 so I could close my db connection. There is also `readableEnded` for node version 12.9