# AWS Lambda & Node: Write data while streaming - ends prematurely and data is missing

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, node-streams

I've got a Lambda function that is triggered by a write to an S3 bucket. It reads the JSON file that is written to the bucket, parses out the individual records, and writes them to a database.

Problem is; I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, because the stream ends and the Lambda exits before all the data is written.

I'm in "flowing mode" on my readable stream, and I'm pausing/resuming during the db write. According to the docs, this should do the trick, but it's not working as expected.

Lambda handler:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    let result = false;
    try {
        result = await parseData(event);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
    return result;
};
```

Promise:

```
const StreamArray = require("stream-json/streamers/StreamArray");

async parseData(event) {
    try {
        let objectStream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
        const streamParser = StreamArray.withParser();
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            objectStream.pipe(streamParser).on("data", async streamData => {
                objectStream.pause();
                let result = await writeData(streamData);
                objectStream.resume();
            }).on("finish", () => {
                console.log("STREAM FINISH!");
                resolve(true);
            }).on("error", e => {
                console.error("Stream error:", e);
                reject(e);
            });
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: How large is the JSON file? Do you actually need to stream it?

Comment: @jarmod It could be very large and I can't predict the size, so it should be streamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working by simply swapping-out stream-json with JSONStream, which is a more widely-used package anyhow. Works like a charm now!

```
const JSONStream = require("JSONStream");

async parseData(event) {
    try {
        let objectStream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
        const streamParser = JSONStream.parse("*");
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            objectStream.pipe(streamParser).on("data", async streamData => {
                streamParser.pause();
                let result = await writeData(streamData);
                streamParser.resume();
            }).on("finish", () => {
                console.log("STREAM FINISH!");
                resolve(true);
            }).on("error", e => {
                console.error("Stream error:", e);
                reject(e);
            });
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```